# Creating a coordinated and centralized multi agents system in python

Tags: python

I'm actually working on a project where I have to coordinate a multitude of autonomous vehicles in a parking. 
I can find a path for each vehicle but I don't really know how to make all vehicle interact in the same time without any collision.

my strategy is this one:

1. Find a path for the vehicle entering the park.
2. Check if there are common way points between the vehicle's path and the other's paths.
3. If there are common points, call a function to change the path of the vehicle or the other vehicle's path.

For two vehicles it works. But how to do it with a multitude ? I think that time should have a place in it, but I don't know exactly how I should do it.

sorry for the spelling mistakes. It's my first post and I'm just starting coding in python. If necessary I can share my code ( it's just really long and to understand it it would take time).

Thank you !

```
freePos = ['1504']
path = get_path(source,freePos)
print(" My car's path:", path)
car2Position = ['1534']
for spot in car2Position:
    s = get_path(spot, dest)
    print(" car 2's path :", s)

    common = commonWaypoints(path, s)
    if common:
        p, n = changePath(path, s) # a function that changes a path 
        if n ==1: # tells if we changed the first or the second path
            path = p
        elif n ==2 :
            s = p # I have to send this path to the other car 
    print (path)  # I print The path Of my car ( actual one)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Including the main points of your code will help us, help you. If it's a really long script try to cut it down to just the necessary parts (like the path finding and checking for common way points). Without it is harder to come up with a solution in line with what you are looking for, as we have no idea what you have so far.

Comment: I just added the code I use in the main file  to test everything. The function changePath() splits the path if it finds that there are common points and changes the path from the nearest intersection.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok if vehicles paths have touch points, as long as it's not at the same time. One approach could be to calculate all paths over a timeline - see at which time paths cross - implement wait behavior. Another, maybe easier, approach could be to broadcast current location at (t) and location at (t+1) for each agent to a central channel. If a (t+1) location is going to interfere with any 
 other vehicles' t+1 location, implement logic to deal with this (eg. right first).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already thought about these kind of solutions. The best one is the first, but I actually don't know how to do it. And for the second one, I can check for the next positions, but if we have a car 10 or 20 positions far from t+1 position it won't work. I thought about a tree search like solution. Where i execute the same code for all pairs of vehicles in the parking until I find an optimal solution. But the problem, is that , like you said, I can have two cars in the same path ...